# Accessing camera over ngrok

Tags: networking, routing, tunnel, ip-camera

I am able to install and and access my webserver over internet by running a ngrok client.

Now I intend to access the RTP stream which means the link need to start with rtmp:// . While ngrok provides an option to set url with tcp:// http://. How to go about setting rtmp://

Answer (score -1):

Late answer but use ngrok with tcp on port 1935 which is the default port for RTMP unless you set it to something else.